# Convert route with dynamic parts to string

Tags: scala, routes, playframework-2.0

I have a dynamic route in Play 2.2.2 that spans several `/`

```
GET /file/*fileName     Controllers.Application.download(fileName)
```

What's the best way to convert `fileName` into a non URI encoded, regular string. That is, without %20 for spaces etc?

Comment: The best approach (no irony) is saving files without spaces and special chars, occasionally use UTF-8 on both sides (note if nobody will answer I'll find later way to decode the urls)

Comment: @biesior I couldn't agree with you more! Sadly that is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.net.URLDecoder.decode

filename = decode(filename, "UTF-8")
```

Comment: Certainly a valid answer and I will accept it. I was curious if Play had a more idiomatic way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?